# How to reform JSON in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working on JSON in iOS swift,

I will query data from  server as,

`results = [{"type":"fruit", "name":"orange"},
{"type":"flower", "name":"rose"},
{"type":"fruit", "name":"apple"}]`

I need to append above data to `TableView` based on the `type`, so that it will be displayed as shown below,

---

### fruit

orange

apple

---

### flower

rose

---

In order to display in `TableView`, the `results` should reform as,

`updatedResult[String:[AnyObject]]() = {
 "fruit":[{"name":"orange"},{"name":"apple"}],
 "flower":[{"name":"rose"}]
}`

How is it possible to reform the `results` to `updatedResult` using swift?

Comment: Why don't you ask to your web developer to give response like that?

Comment: Not sure what updatedResult[String:[AnyObject]]() is. But I am guessing you need to use pod 'JSONModel'

Comment: @SimonMoshenko, `updatedResult[String:[AnyObject]]()` is a `(key,value)` pair where `key` is of type `String` and `value` is of type `Array` (of type `AnyObject`)

Comment: @AshishKakkad, Actually, I will query for the data and It cannot be altered.

Comment: What about writing code for it? You have an array of dictionaries, each with a type and a name, collecting dictionaries with the same type should be trivial. Then you turn identical types into sections, and the names into rows for the sections, and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Your example json    
results = [{"type":"fruit", "name":"orange"},{"type":"flower","name":"rose"},{"type":"fruit", "name":"apple"}]
```

First you need to turn your json into an array of dictionaries to get the above object you think it will be:

```
if let results = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [[String : AnyObject]] 
{ //parse into form you want.}

// Your example desired result of dictionary with key:array of dictionaries
updatedResult[String:[AnyObject]]() = {"fruit":[{"name":"orange"},{"name":"apple"}],"flower":[{"name":"rose"}]}
```

Then you want to loop through the json result and grab out the values into the above format you want:

```
// Swift representation of your provided example
let results = [["type":"fruit", "name":"orange"],["type":"flower","name":"rose"],["type":"fruit", "name":"apple"]]

// Desired dictionary of key:array of dictionaries
var updatedResult = [String:[[String:String]]]()

for item in results {
    if let name = item["name"], type = item["type"] {
        if updatedResult.keys.contains(type) {
            updatedResult[type]!.append(["name":name])
        } else {
            updatedResult[type] = [["name":name]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is my pleasure to help.